# Html currency symbol are not showing in chrome

Tags: html

I have one html currency symbol code:

```html
<span>&#8377; 184.90</span>
```

When i run this code then getting one square symbol instead of INR symbol in chrome browser, But in firefox it's looks fine. How to display the same one in any browser?

Answer (score 2):

It probably depends which font is used by the browser and if that font contains a glyph/character for that code. Try to assign another font to it (only to the currency symbol code, not to the number) of which you know that it works, like `<span style="font-family:Arial;">`

```html
<span style="font-family:Arial;">&#8377;</span> 184.90
```